# Emacs `make-mode` indentation settings

Tags: emacs

Plain `emacs`' `make-mode` indents a [multi line variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html) in a counterintuitive way:

```
define SOURCE_DIRS =
utils
utils/string
utils/stream
tools
tools/config
tools/io
endef
```

A more intiuitive and clear indentation would be:

```
define SOURCE_DIRS =
    utils
    utils/string
    utils/stream
    tools
    tools/config
    tools/io
endef
```

Can `emacs`/`make-mode` be configured to produce the desired indentation?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to have emacs auto-indent this so that you don't have to press tab for each line?

Comment: Yes, kind of. More importantly, I want emacs to think it is good that there's a `tab`, i.e. if I run `indent-region` I don't want emacs to remove the inserted indent.